# How do you move the search bar next to the logo?

Tags: magento

I am using Magento 1.9.2 and would like to move the search bar from the right in the RWD theme, so that it is next to the logo. Like amazon have their search bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using rwd theme of default magento then open header.phtml file.

app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\page\html\header.phtml

And put this code around line number 49 after logo code.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
```

Now just make searchbox **display none** which is already in header(will be used in responsive)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: HI Makwana, the search bar itself is present. Just needs moving so its situated inline with the logo and the account and cart buttons. Like on amazon!

Comment: I have managed to get it to appear next to the logo, but it literally is right at top. Just need to make it align with the bottom of the logo, and then move the account and cart buttons next to the search bar

Comment: If you dont know much more about css then you should get help from your colleague. Because I cant help you without watching html and css.:)

Comment: I have nearly solved it! Just want to make the logo and the search bar align at the bottom. Tried bottom 0, but it still sticks to top.

Comment: May I ask if you know why the search bar is not aligning to bottom or possible errors that can cause this ?